# Hypergeometric distribution and Fisher's exact test

Tags: probability, distributions, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

I have looked around but I cannot seem to find a conclusive answer. Does the Hypergeometric distribution assume that the probability of selecting a defective item at any point is equal to that of selecting a non-defective item?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about a binary variable, with two values 0 and 1, say, which in your applications you want to think as labelling non-defective and defective states. How does that relate to a hypergeometric at all? Where does Fisher's exact test come in? (I may be missing something simple.)

Comment: Fisher's exact test is used in combining two arm clinical trials which test treatment against placebo. The null hypothesis assumes that the probability of success in the treatment group is equal to that in the placebo group. If the null hypothesis is of that form, the number of successes in the treatment group follow a hyper geometric distribution. My question is why is that the case? The only reasonable argument that comes to me is that in a  single trial of hypgeo the probability of selecting a non defective (so treatment success) is equal to selecting a defective (so placebo success).

Comment: Thanks. I don't follow all of this, but I want you to get your question in better shape, so do edit this into your question. Picky point: as already flagged by an edit, the standard spelling is one word, _hypergeometric_.